# Is it possible to divide cells in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to make some columns have 3 cells inside one cell (example on the screenshot). I tried to do it in different ways: using rowSpan, changing the height of the row/cells, but none of these ways worked for me.
How can I implement this in ag-grid ?

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqAwq.png)

Comment: Why didn't row spanning work? It seems exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: When using row spanning (e.g. rowSpan: () => 3 ), each row increases in size but overlaps the next 2 rows. And so for each row.

Comment: Yes, as in your screenshot. Instead of dividing one row into three, you have three rows and span the cell across them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Row Spanning, please see this implemented in the [following Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zlT5wUhJJwTLTvbx)

The key here is the `rowSpan` callback:

```
const rowSpan = (params) => {
  const columnId = params.column.getColId();
  if (params.data[columnId] === 'row 1') {
    return 3;
  } else if (params.data[columnId] === 'row 2') {
    return 3;
  } else if (params.data[columnId] === 'row 3') {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
};
```

Comment: So far it looks like the only possible solution, but is there a way to do it without manipulating the raw data? 
I mean, in your solution there are separate rows in rowData { d: 'cell 2' }, { d: 'cell 3' }. I would like all 3 cells (cell 1, cell 2, cell 3) to belong to their row (row 1) and not be put in separate rows

Comment: You could keep the raw data how it is, but you'd have to add a function to mutate the data so that new rows are created based on the raw data, and so that rowSpan would work